# Mysql select next 1000 rows starting from next row after provided

Tags: mysql

I need to select next 1000 rows starting from the row where the unique field is next after provided for the table without autoincrement field.

Example (for simplicity limit will be 2 rows):
I have table colors:

```
UID    | COLOR
---------------
15546  | Green
234534 | Blue
7435   | Yellow
8354   | Red
534654 | White
1053425| Black
1142352| Brown
```

and I need to select next 2 rows after the row with UID 234534. So I need to select rows with UID 7435 and 8354.

Pseudocode:

```
select * from colors where UID is next after :UID order by UID limit 2
```

Comment: And what column indicates the order of the records?

Comment: Unless there's a specific mechanism to identify the order of rows, you can't do that. Do you have an auto-increment field or similar?

Comment: UID is a unique field and I use it to order rows, but this field is not MAX+1

Comment: 'I use it to order rows' How does that work?

Comment: Okay, maybe I used a bad example, in the real-world situation `UID` is an integer field with a unique index. And I can order by that field

Answer (score 0):

```
set @row_number=0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Temp_Colors (SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, UID, color FROM colors);
set @row_num = (Select num From Temp_Colors Where uid='8ad');
SELECT UID, color FROM Temp_Colors Where num > @row_num
```

You can implement this by using create temp table from existing data by generating column row_number and then you can play with temp data as you have temporary auto incremented column.